# Maintain hover on nested list ul

Tags: jquery, css, menu

See my [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/zrs95fk8/2/)

I am nearly there I think.

I'de like the nested `<ul>`'s to slide out when their parent is hovered over.

This works fine BUT when you try to hover over the nested  it switches to the last nested `<ul>` options. You'll see in the example above - the menu switches to the "International" items each time you hover over.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('li.has-children').hover(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).children('ul').addClass('nav-open');
    }, function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('li.has-children > ul').removeClass('nav-open');
    }); 

});
```

CSS:

```
ul.main-menu {
            float: left;
            width: 33%;
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            background: white;
            font-size: 1.3em;
            padding: 0;
      background:red;
        }

            ul.main-menu li {
                width: 100%;
                float: left;
            }           

            ul.main-menu li a {
                display: block;
                float: left;
                width: 100%;
                padding:13px 0;
                color: #333;
                position: relative;
            }


            ul.main-menu li ul {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                top:0;
                left: 100%;
                opacity: 0;
                transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
            }

            ul.main-menu ul.nav-open {
                opacity: 1;
                left: 90%;
            }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look like this :

see : https://jsfiddle.net/ainouss/23asw6d1/1/#&togetherjs=PIa9R7MsUx

```
ul.main-menu {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background: white;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    padding: 0;
}
.has-children{
    border:1px solid red;
}
.has-children ul{
    display:none;
}

ul.main-menu li {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

ul.main-menu li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding:13px 0;
    color: #333;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for messing up with your styling, you can still update it;

Comment: I cant get this to work with my styling. I need the sub nav to slide out at the top of the main list, and not the parent list item. I noticed you changed the JS and CSS, is it the JS that is answering my question? Thanks

Comment: if you still want to align it top, see http://jsfiddle.net/ainouss/ok1zsgu4 but you should change the sub-drop-down min-hight to get it work perfectly.

Comment: by the way you don't need event.stopPropagation()

Comment: The change that answered your question is:

display : none by defalut, 
display : block when hover occurs.